# SP16 - Button click refresh page when i Use PnP-Core-JS

Tags: ajax, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, refresh, button

My webpart is for SP16. I use code from [**this sample**](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/master/samples/sharepoint-crud/src/webparts/spPnPJsCrud/SpPnPJsCrudWebPart.ts) and when i click button in webpart, page is refreshed.

**This is code for Create Item:**

```
 private createItem(): void {
this.updateStatus('Creating item...');
pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle(this.properties.listName).items.add({
  'Title': `Item ${new Date()}`
}).then((result: ItemAddResult): void => {
  const item: IListItem = result.data as IListItem;
  this.updateStatus(`Item '${item.Title}' (ID: ${item.Id}) successfully created`);
}, (error: any): void => {
  this.updateStatus('Error while creating the item: ' + error);
});
```

}

**HTML:**

```
<button class="${styles.button} create-Button">
    <span class="${styles.label}">Create item</span>
</button>
```

**Declare Event:**

```
const webPart: SpFxOnPrenPnPjsWebPart = this;
this.domElement.querySelector('button.create-Button').addEventListener('click', () => { webPart.createItem(); });
```

I would like the page not to be reloaded when clicking a button? How do It?

Comment: share the HTML that you are using to create a button ..

Comment: My Code: https://github.com/geogikk92/SPFx-On-Prem-CRUD-with-PnpJS/blob/master/src/webparts/spFxOnPrenPnPjs/SpFxOnPrenPnPjsWebPart.ts

Comment: Refer this link. This may work for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33465557/how-to-stop-page-reload-on-button-click-jquery